# jQuery syntax issue for basic id selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  <div class="wpsc_buy_button_container">
    <input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Customize', 'wpsc'); ?>" name="Customize" 
      class="wpsc_customize_button" id="product_<?php echo wpsc_the_product_id(); ?>_customize_button"/>
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#product_<?php echo wpsc_the_product_id(); ?>_customize_button").click(function() {
    alert('product clicked');
  });
  alert('test click');
</script>
```

View->Source Gives:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#product_53_customize_button").click(function() {
    alert('product clicked');
  });
  alert('test click');
</script>
```

Is there something wrong with the syntax as I don't see my alerts.  If I remove the single jQuery line then the test alert begins to work.

Comment: What the...I had to take out the $ and put in jQuery does anyone know why this is or how I could have known this with out trial and error?

Comment: You may have `jquery.noConflict()` active or another library loaded that is using `$` such as prototype

Comment: This is a WP install it must be standard to be in no-conflict mode for WP

Comment: Were you using Mootools with or without [noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)?

Comment: It is indeed standard in wordpress as [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers)

Comment: In the javascript console of your browser you should've got something in the lines of "$ is undefined" or '$() is nor a function'. That's the way you realize you're having that problem.

Answer (score 0):

this is you are not using jquery event

use this

```
$(function(){
    $("#product_53_customize_button").click(function() {
        alert('product clicked');
      });

    })
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#product_53_customize_button").click(function() {
            alert('product clicked');
          });

        })
```